# Why does my Hamming weight function work in C but not in Rust?

Tags: rust, hammingweight

I've got the following Hamming weight code in Rust, and it returns garbage for `0xffff` and `0xffffffff`, but the identical code in C works, so I must be misunderstanding something about how Rust does bit-level operations.  It's completely parenthesized, so I don't think it's an operator-precedence issue.

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int hamming_weight(int val) {
    int v1 = val - ((val >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    int v2 = (v1 & 0x33333333) + ((v1 >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((v2 + (v2 >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
}

int main() {
    printf("%x -> %d\n", 7, hamming_weight(7));
    printf("%x -> %d\n", 0xff, hamming_weight(0xff));
    printf("%x -> %d\n", 0xffff, hamming_weight(0xffff));
    printf("%x -> %d\n", 0xffffffff, hamming_weight(0xffffffff));
    return 0;
}
```

The results:

```
7 -> 3
ff -> 8
ffff -> 16
ffffffff -> 32
```

In Rust (I had to use u64 to prevent overflow panics on `0xffff`):

```rust
fn hamming_weight(val: u64) -> u64 {
    let v1 = val - ((val >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    let v2 = (v1 & 0x33333333) + ((v1 >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    (((v2 + (v2 >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:x} {}", 7, hamming_weight(7));
    println!("{:x} {}", 0xff, hamming_weight(0xff));
    println!("{:x} {}", 0xffff, hamming_weight(0xffff));
    println!("{:x} {}", 0xffffffffu32, hamming_weight(0xffffffffu64));
}
```

The results:

```
7 3
ff 8
ffff 2064
ffffffff 135272480
```

I'm using Rust 1.16. I know Rust has `count_ones()` - the compiler told me when I was writing this code, which was pretty amazing, but I am choosing to not use it.

Comment: "I know Rust has count_ones() - the compiler told me when I was writing this code" → When did it tell you?

Comment: Replace the declaration with `fn hamming_weight(val: u64) -> u32`.  

I get this error message: `help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs: ... - .count_ones()`.  The rust compiler's error messages are amazing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I had to use `u64` to prevent overflow panics on `0xffff`

That's your problem. The original C code *relies* on the operation overflowing. Increasing the size of the type doesn't fix it, but allowing the overflow to wrap does:

```
fn hamming_weight(val: u32) -> u32 {
    let v1 = val - ((val >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    let v2 = (v1 & 0x33333333) + ((v1 >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    (((v2 + (v2 >> 4)) & 0xF0F0F0F).wrapping_mul(0x1010101)) >> 24
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that was baffling.